# javascript setting top value inside a function

Tags: javascript

```
$('#navbr').affix({
 offset: {
     top: $('headerdiv').height()
}       
});
```

I have another div `#banner`. I want to set the top margin of that inside the function.

I have tried the following but it didn't work

```
$('#navbr').affix({
 offset: {
     top: $('headerdiv').height()
     $(#banner).css('top', '40px'); 
}       
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run it after that function:

```
$('#navbr').affix({
    offset: {
        top: $('headerdiv').height()
    }       
});
$("#banner").css('top', '40px');
```